Export coordinates of connector elements in abaqus using history output
I am working on a model with numbers of connector section element (cartesian) and in history output i could find connector element total force (CTF) and relative displacement (CU). But I need connector position to plot the force-distribution diagram showing the force status at certain step. I don't find the coordinate output for the connectors.
Can anyone help me to access the undeformed and deformed coordinates of the connector section elements.
I tried with current nodal coordinates (COORD) but it doesn't work for the connector element.
Regards
Rajan
